# How to combine first-of-type and first-line together?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
article#tour_summary p:first-of-type(1) {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
article#tour_summary p::first-line {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

So my question is how would I join these two commands? I want the first paragraph and only the first line to be capitalize  font-size: 1.2em, and small caps.

This is what I was asked to do, "Adriana wants the first line in the tour_summary article to appear in small capital letters. Use the first-of-type pseudo-class and the first-line pseudo-element to create a style rule that displays the first line of the first paragraph within the tour_summary article at a font size of 1.2em and in small caps."

Comment: First off.. You shouldn't be posting your homework questions. Secondly, check the syntax for `first-of-type`.

Comment: You don't have to be a jack**s, if you don't wanna help just don't... thanks

Comment: @blackandorangecat indeed a simple search on Google by him would have avoided this question... btw we're all learning...

Comment: @caiovisk I agree. My main objection was to quoting the assignment in the question, rather than just asking for programming help.

Comment: @blackandorangecat: There's nothing wrong with quoting the assignment in the question if it provides context *and* the user has shown their attempt. In this case, it's probably just a little bit unnecessary since the asker has already restated it in their own words, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's uncalled for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first-of-type` do not accept parameters, so you can combine `:first-of-type` and `:first-line` as well, see:

```
article#tour_summary p:first-of-type:first-line {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp

```css
article#tour_summary p:first-of-type:first-line {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<article id="tour_summary">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, esse nulla delenit nec ei. Quo sapientem elaboraret ut, vero impedit sit no. An noster dolorem his. Partem tamquam scaevola at has. Blandit omnesque ea vel, ut has ancillae eligendi fabellas. Dictas praesent ei eum.</p>
<p>Ei erant decore pertinax nec. Ex duo errem tation inermis. Pro ut vocibus commune. Eos no tale sanctus. Est errem labitur ad, iudicabit necessitatibus id vix, pri an unum admodum. In eos mutat recusabo.</p>
<p>Vix id malis detracto. Pro agam appareat dissentiunt eu, vero vivendo cu vis, quaeque menandri erroribus nec et. Veritus civibus et sit. Eam ea iriure ponderum omittantur. Dicta partiendo ullamcorper mel no.</p>
<p>Vix te homero electram inciderint, aliquip percipit persequeris ad mei. Pri zril labitur ad, choro theophrastus his ut. Mel persius propriae dissentiet te. An duo quas augue periculis, ea modo consulatu quo. In per reque nostrum. Ne eum minim sonet semper, usu illum officiis disputando et, ad lucilius torquatos has.</p>
<p>No sale mentitum facilisis pro, ea appetere sapientem theophrastus mea. Est quando feugiat ea, sea ut nibh rebum, quod ullamcorper mea cu. Eam ad liber postea labore. Ad per dictas petentium, mel ad eirmod repudiandae neglegentur, quidam assueverit no quo. Ad est eius sanctus, labitur ullamcorper ut duo. Omnium imperdiet ad cum.</p>
</article>
```